# How do I stop an inheritly positioned element from jumping up page when I change the div above it to fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have a page that uses Javascript to fix the header to the top of the page (thus removing the banner) when you scroll past the bottom of the banner (about 200px down page).

On this website I've been using containers that have the `position:inherit;` property set to contain each part of the page. These then have a relatively positioned element inside them so I can place all my absolutely positioned elements where I like.

My problem is that `id="content"` keeps jumping to the top of the page when the Javascript changes `id="header"` to `position:fixed;`.

I have tried absolutely positioning `id="content"` and setting its top value but it wouldn't work and I'm a bit stuck.

Here is a very simplified version of the HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">                <!--inherit-->
    <a id="banner"></a>          <!--inherit-->
    <div id="header">            <!--inherit-->
      <div id="lang">            <!--relative-->
        <ul>...</ul>             <!--inherit-->
        <other divs>             <!--absolute-->
      </div>
      <div id="nav">             <!--relative-->
        <ul>..</ul>              <!--inherit-->
        <a id="userbutton"></a>  <!--absolute-->
      </div>
    </div
    <div id="content0">          <!--inherit-->
      <div id="content">         <!--relative-->
        <PAGE CONTENT>           <!--absolute-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my javascript:

```js
var bannerheight // Glob var
    
window.onload = function() {
    window.bannerheight = $('#bannerimg').height();
    checkOffset();
};

window.onscroll = function(oEvent) {
    checkOffset();
}

function checkOffset() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= window.bannerheight) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("banner").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("padding").style.height = window.bannerheight+"px";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.position = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("banner").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("padding").style.height = "0px";
    }
}
```

and here is the relevant CSS:

```css
#page {
    margin:0px auto;
}
#lang {
    position:relative;
}   
#nav {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
}   
#content0 {
    height:800px;
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the content div a "margin-top" and set it to the number of pixels that the page is "jumping".  Then when you scroll up and reset the position, undo the margin-top back to zero.

I've tested this and it solved my jumping issue.

Comment: You can provide example for better understanding.

Comment: I've actually resolved the issue now. I shall find out what I did to solve this and post an answer when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expect as output but `position: fixed` works on the document, globally. It not only ignores element flow (like `position: absolute`) but it also ignores scrolling.

`position: absolute` is relative to it's offset parent which can be an item with `position: relative`.

You typically only want to use `position: fixed` if something needs to stick to the window, like a little popup that scrolls with as you go down the page. The Facebook header is a good example. Their header bar is fixed to the top of the window and stays there even if you scroll.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. I want the header of the page to scroll with the page until the bottom of the banner disappears and then I want the rest of the header to remain fixed as you scroll down the rest of the page. It's working fine, it's just that the next group of elements all move up the page ontop of the fixed header

Comment: If you click the link and scroll down slowly with the scroll bar and mouse (don't use the mouse wheel) you'll see what I mean

Comment: When you set `position: fixed`, make sure you give the other elements an offset to fill the empty space.

Comment: As I said already. I tried giving "content" a top value and setting it's position to absolute, but it didn't work. There is also a divider below the header called "padding" which gets expanded in the javascript code